How do I set the weight to all faces that are selected in edit mode?
I would like to set the weight paint to 1.0 to all the faces I've selected in Edit Mode, however, none of the answers online work for Blender 4.0 and are incredibly vague.
Could someone explain in detail the process to do this?

For "faces" it's impossible.
For "vertices" it's feasible.
Weight painting works on "point domain".
You can select the vertices that surround your face and then the entire face will be weighted (but that will create a gradient around these faces). There is no workaround, though (but you could make the surrounding faces smaller for a sharper gradient).
While in edit mode, for a "mesh" object, go to the "vertex groups" section of your object:

The arrows show the main options:

Create new group (or select the existing group you want)
Select vertices on the object and use the "assign" button to set the weights of these vertices
Adjust the desired weight before assigning

Other options are:

Button to automatically select/deselect all points with weights
Button to remove the wights from selected vertices

